# Finding the content type of the uploaded file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, arrays, mime-types, stringio

I am working on ruby on rails. I am trying to do a file attachment (image/audio/video) .

So i have a common method like

```
byteArray = StringIO.new(File.open("path").read)
```

Is it possible to find the content type of the byteArray to check whether the uploaded file is a image/audio/video/pdf in ruby.

Comment: Are you using paperclip for file uploading?

Comment: @Ramiz Raja  ya once i set the content type for the attachment , i used to save it via paperclip. Currently i have 3 separate methods for saving one for images, audio and video. So i am trying to generalize it so that to find the content type of the byteArray and to set the content type and  save it in Paperclip

Comment: you can get `content type` of uploaded file as `paperclip` generate column `<model_name>_content_type` for the uploaded file.

Comment: Are you looking to restrict upload by file type?

Answer (score 7):

I saw this was tagged `paperclip`, so I will give you how we do it with paperclip:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

        has_attached_file :attachment,
                styles:          lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}},
                :processors => lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }

        def is_video?
                attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
        end

        def is_image?
                attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
        end

end
```

If you manage to get your file into Paperclip, it basically cuts it up into content_type already. This means that if you use a [`lambda`](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) to determine whether the attachment content_type contains `image` or `video`

If you give me some more info on what you're trying to achieve, I can give you some refactored code to help with your issue specifically :)

Comment: do you know why for styles lambda receives attachment file object, but for processors it receives attachment model object?

Comment: Nope sorry - that code is likely out of date now too :(